# How to improve CROSS JOIN request memory consumption

Tags: sql, h2

For simulation purposes, I need to randomly create rows in a table.
I have a table A of possible situations and a table B of possible events with a probability column.

```
CREATE TABLE Situations (
  SituationId INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY HASH
);
CREATE TABLE B Events (
  EventId INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY HASH,
  EventProbability DECIMAL(13,10) NOT NULL
);
```

To create the events, I use a CROSS JOIN request:

```
CREATE TABLE GeneratedEvents
AS (SELECT SituationId, EventId FROM (SELECT SituationId, EventId, RAND() * 100 AS GenerationProbability, EventProbability FROM Situations CROSS JOIN Events) WHERE GenerationProbability < EventProbability);
```

I'm using h2 database in memory mode only (i.e. with the following URL: jdbc:h2:mem:db) and the problem is that with around 72k rows in Situations table and 600 rows in Events table, i'm running out of memory of the JVM. I'm using memory mode to be able to run several JVM in parallel.

I suppose that using a CROSS JOIN request is not the best solution. Any idea how to improve memory consumption and execution performances by avoiding to create unnecessary records?
Thanks,
Laurent

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get the required result without using the CROSS JOIN request in a subquery (which was the main memory problem as the results of this subquery needed to be loaded fully in memory) with the following request:

```
CREATE TABLE GeneratedEvents
AS (SELECT SituationId, EventId FROM Situations A CROSS JOIN Events WHERE (SELECT RAND() * 100 FROM Situations B WHERE B.SituationId = A.SituationId) < EventProbability);
```

The subquery:

```
(SELECT RAND() * 100 FROM Situations B WHERE B.SituationId = A.SituationId)
```

in the WHERE clause is used to force the RAND() value to be 'evaluated' each time, otherwise it seems to be cached or something as just using RAND() * 100 should be sufficient for the searched result. This subquery is certainly not optimum for execution performances or maybe not working any more if I have just a few rows in the Situations table, but it is currently the best solution I've found.